# Directive listening for click event with 3 paramaters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive listening for a click event and picking up the parameter values but all 3 values are showing up in the debugger as param 1's value, with param 2 & 3 being undefined.

**Html:**

```
<div my-directive data-ng-click="(vm.id, vm.title, vm.name)"></div>
```

**Directive:**

```
.directive('myDirective', ['config', function (config) {
    // ...
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      // ...
      // click event
      elem.bind('click', function () {
        attrs.$observe('onClick', function (param1, param2, param3) {
        // ...
```

How should the `ng-click` parameter values in the html be written for the values to be picked up individually by the directive?

Comment: ng-click should call a function on the scope. if you use ng-click you will not need to bind the event manually. You can bind your `vm` object to the directive's scope to access it. Then you don't need to pass the parameters from the view. If you must pass them from the view, then define them in your scope function. [Read up on directives here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: To add to Nick's point, the `data-ng-click` attribute would look like `data-ng-click="myFunc(vm.id, vm.title, vm.name)"`. `myFunc` would look like `$scope.myFunc = function( id, title, name ) { console.log( id, title, name ); }`. I believe the easiest way to make this work would be defining `scope: false` within `myDirective`'s return object definition.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
 <div my-directive data-ng-click="ClickMe();" 
          data-param1="SampleA" data-param2="SampleB" data-param3="SampleC"> </div>
```

**Directive:**

```
 .directive('myDirective', ['config', function (config) {

      ..............

        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            ..................
            // click event
            elem.bind('click', function () {
                attrs.$observe('onClick', function () {
               ......
            var result1 = attrs.param1;
            var result2 = attrs.param2;
            var result3 = attrs.param3;
              .....
            if (result1 != undefined && result2 != undefined && result3 != undefined) {
                switch (result1) {
                 case "SampleA":
                  // call parent controller on directive's html page
                   scope.vm.MyCtrl1Function(result1, result2, result3);
                   break;
                       .................
                  }
              };
          });
      }]);
```